# Why are arrow methods not allowed in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, programming-languages, arrow-functions

The suggestions to allow arrow methods in Typescript have been rejected on the basis on "changing Javascript as language". How would it exactly change the language to have one less character in the function declaration (see `add2` and `add3` in the example below)?

This is especially confusing to hear considering all other changes Typescript has accumulated compared to Javascript over the years.

```
export class Point {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
    }

    add1(p: Point): Point {
        return new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y)
    }

    add2 = (p: Point) => new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y)

    add3(p: Point) => new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y)
    
    ...
```

**EDIT**

Added links to some of the suggestions

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18500
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24196#issuecomment-389897467

Comment: ① Could you link to these suggestions in your question?  Presumably the authoritative answer to this question would be found in the TS team's responses on those issues.

Comment: ② The TypeScript language has [design goals](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) that, at this point, essentially prohibit making any runtime-observable changes unless they are part of an upcoming proposal for JavaScript itself. Arrow methods, if they are a good idea, should happen in JS, and TS will support them when they reach Stage 3 in the TC39 proposal process. Older TS changes that violate this are essentially artifacts of an earlier era before these goals solidified.  I'd be happy to write up an answer about this, but I'd like to see ① answered first.

Comment: Just a heads up, you do know that because your using `this`,  `add1()` is the only one that makes any sense, otherwise your loosing the benefits of the `prototype`.

Comment: @jcalz https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24196#issuecomment-389897467

Comment: @Keith you will have elaborate on what exactly I'm losing with `add2()` - for me it just works

Comment: Sorry, I meant you should [edit] your question to link to those.  Also, the issue you linked to is about *accessor* methods (like `get foo() {}` which would be accessed like `x.foo`) and not methods, so it's not the same as what you're talking about here.  Is there some actual request for "arrow function methods"? Your question says "suggestions" so I'd expect to see more than one link.  Was that a typo and you just meant "suggestion"?

Comment: @jcalz I appreciate your feedback. Edited the question text but basically I'm coming from this search: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues?q=arrow+method+in%3Atitle+. We can't agree that getters are methods?

Comment: @AntonDuzenko  Because `add2` doesn't add it's method to the prototype, instead it adds it to every instance of the class.   IOW: If you created a million instances of `Point`,  there will be a million instances of the `add2` method,  but because `add1` is a prototype method, it only gets created once. It's kind of the whole purpose of the class prototype & `this`.

Comment: So [ms/TS#18500](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18500) is definitely relevant.  It was closed saying that they don't take such feature requests because they don't want to worry about conflicts with future changes to JS. It's a runtime feature, so they want to see it in JS first and then they'll support it. Otherwise what happens is like class fields and decorators: the early TS implementation ended up in conflict with later JS and needed to be completely redone. These features are reasonable, but TS folks have learned the hard way that any runtime changes should come from JS first.

Comment: ^ Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write it up as an answer.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer I am not going to make any value judgments about whether arrow methods would be a good or bad feature, since I don't think that's relevant for the question as asked.

---

TypeScript has a set of [design goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals) for the language.  One listed goal is to align with current and future ECMAScript proposals, and one listed *non-goal* is to provide additional runtime functionality.

Arrow methods are runtime functionality and would be observable at runtime, since presumably writing

```
add3(p: Point) => new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y);
```

would need to transpile to either

```
add3 = (p) => new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y);
```

or maybe

```
add3(p) { return new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y); }
```

so the compiler couldn't merely *erase* something to get the desired JavaScript output.

And arrow methods are not set to be introduced to JavaScript.  So for these reasons, suggestion to add this to TypeScript would be declined, as you saw in [microsoft/TypeScript#18500](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18500).

---

As you noted, though, such guidelines have not always been followed so strictly.  For example, [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) are a TypeScript-only feature with runtime effects.  And there are [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) also.

But there have been several instances over the years where a TypeScript-only runtime feature conflicted with a similar feature introduced later to JavaScript.  [Class field declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) were added first to TypeScript and then to JavaScript, and JavaScript implemented different semantics.  So now TypeScript had to implement a [`--useDefineForClassFields` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) to allow switching between the TypeScript behavior and the expected JavaScript behavior, and thus they have to support *both*, making the language more complex than it needed to be.

Similarly, TypeScript introduced [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) before they were mature enough to know what JavaScript was going to do with them, and again, now we have a legacy decorator implementation sitting alongside a [new decorator implementation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#decorators) and you need to use a compiler flag to switch between them.

This is a big headache for the language.

If JavaScript ever introduces enums or parameter properties, or features similar enough syntactically to conflict, we can expect more headaches.  The TypeScript team is quite reluctant now to opt into such headaches without a very strong reason.  They generally only want to implement runtime features if those features are upcoming JavaScript features whose semantics are stable enough to be fairly confident that the time and effort won't be wasted.  As such a proposed JavaScript feature generally needs to reach Stage 3 of [the TC39 process](https://tc39.es/process-document/) before TypeScript will begin to support it.

No matter how good a suggestion might be, if it's possible for JavaScript to either implement it or interfere with it, TypeScript will almost certainly turn it down.

---

So: if arrow methods are a good idea for TypeScript, they would also be a good idea for JavaScript (except for the type annotations, so it would look like `add3(p) => new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y)` at runtime).  And therefore interested and committed parties should consider [making such a proposal](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/HEAD/CONTRIBUTING.md#new-feature-proposals) to [TC39](https://tc39.es/).  If it is adopted, TypeScript would definitely support it.

Comment: You surely put much more though into the answer that I put into the question

Answer (score 1):

Because in Javascript (and thus in Typescript) arrow functions have no `this` context and that doesn't make sence for class methods

The `add2` is being transpiled into

```
class Point {
    constructor(...a) {
        this.add2 = (p: Point) => new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y);
    }
}
```

so it works, as instance-binded closure and not as a method

Comment: I see your point, but usage of `this` is not strictly relevant to arrow function syntax. It could be just a function returning a const value, for example

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean in general - this function just works for me

Comment: @AntonDuzenko  `just works for me`, if your happy that every instance of Point has a closure over it's own copy of a function, then that's fine.